Contact obstacle in Ansys explicit
I'm trying to simulate the impact problem of a balling to a base in Explicit Ansys. I add a frictional contact between the ball and the base. But it seem Ansys doesn't recognize the contact and the ball is an obstacle with a base.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I try to change many behavior of contact but it seem useless.
Also can anyone help me point to the difference between body interaction and the contact.
